# Does composer have its own concept of consensus?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Does composer have its own concept of consensus or it depends on the underlying fabric consensus which only comes up with the agreed order of transaction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer doesn't have it's own concept of consensus.
As Composer interacts with Hyperledger Fabric it is subject to the same policies as any other deployed chaincode so will be subject to whatever consensus implementation is being utilized by the underlying hyperledger fabric.